# How to send thousands of facebook app notifications at once?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have an app that has thousands of authorized users.  I need to send them a notification.  I can do it with PHP CURL to a single individual just fine:

```
POST /{recipient_userid}/notifications?access_token= … &template= … &href= …
```

but want to know the cleanest way to execute this with a list of 20,000 people.  Would it be a batch Facebook graph call? would it be simply many single PHP CURL calls? what is the best method to do this?  I'm sure many apps already do this with thousands of users.... what is the best method?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usg parallel (rolling) technique of cURL.